# What is a word for the genre of literature of which Tolkien is the high priest and founder, in its 20th-century incarnation.?

Tags: word-choice

What is a word for the form of literature that evokes images of supernatural creatures like goblins, elves, hobbits etc. in Tolkienian surroundings of misty mountains, caverns, underground lakes etc.

Comment: It's a form of Fantasy literature, usually colluded with Science Fiction literature, as F/SF. One can get much more particular than that, but local fan terms vary considerably.

Comment: You could look around [Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/about). 175 questions tagged Tolkien.

Comment: Q: What do you call a sci-fi story that's clearly ripped off from another author?
A:  Peculative fiction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

More specific than "fantasy fiction", Tolkien has been described in [The Encyclopedia of Fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Encyclopedia_of_Fantasy) as the father of [*high* fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_fantasy) (also known as *epic* fantasy), a genre "defined as fantasy fiction set in an alternative, entirely fictional ('secondary') world, rather than the real, or 'primary' world".

Comment: Certainly not epic fantasy; that's been around since Gilgamesh. But "High Fantasy" as a genre label is not bad. It echoes Tolkien's implicit class system with High Elves and Wood Elves, Men of the West and common folk, etc. There's a definite vertical element all through Tolkien, which I'm sure was intentional; he knew all about myths and tales and their making, and what kind of presuppositions they require.

Answer (score 4):

As *lies breathed through silver*, I believe Tolkien would have preferred to label his works as ***mythopoeia***, a term apparently coined by him (and a title of one of his poems). As works that may not necessarily be universally appreciated as *high* or *grand* this label is my personal preference too.

> creation of myths (OED)

Another grandiose term used by [Tolkien himself](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Legendarium) to refer to his *middle-earth* works is ***legendarium***.

Answer (score 2):

What booksellers pigeonhole it as is "Science Fiction and Fantasy". If you go into a large bookstore in the US, there will be [a section labeled that](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/u/Science-Fiction-Fantasy-Books-Bestsellers-New-Releases/379003055/). If the store has Tolkien, his works will be in that section. In addition, we have a sister StackExchange site named [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), where most Tolkien-related questions will probably be rated on topic.

Now a lot of *readers* prefer not to lump the two together like that ("prefer" being perhaps a gigantic understatement)<sup>1</sup>. You can see a hint of this over at the SF stack, in that they felt compelled to put "Science Fiction" and "Fantasy" in completely different fonts in the stack's own title.

There are oodles of recognized subgenres within each of those two (sub?)genres, of which Tolkien is generally put into [High Fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_fantasy) within the [Fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantasy) genre. I find this eminently fair, as pretty much any other work that qualifies as High Fantasy will be discussed in part on how it compares to Tolkien (eg: Does it have Tolkienesque races? How does its magic system compare?). If you'd like to know more, I'd suggest looking at some of the tag definitions at [SF.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags).

Comment: 1 - I personally argue against this, but its not a popular opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard it called 'High Fantasy' or 'Grand Fantasy'. The most common Q&A is 'What is High Fantasy?' 'Tolkien'

Answer (score 0):

fantasy fiction would be a suitable descriptor, no?